# how to formulate a recipe in 1 record type or function

Tags: f#

I would like to be able to express some `Measure` of a specific type in a variety of ways. This is a very wacky example.

> 1. If we are cooking Lamb, then we will need 3 tablespoons of olive oil, 1 cup of sugar, and 3 ounces of butter.
> 2. If we are cooking pie, then we will need 10 tablespoons of olive oil, and 1 ounce of salt
> 3. If we area cooking steak, then we will need 5 ounces of salt, 4 pounds of ice cream.

I have different measures:

```
[<Measure>] type Tablespoon
[<Measure>] type Ounce
[<Measure>] type Pounds
```

We also have the different foods we'd like to cook:

```
type Foods = 
    | Lamb
    | Pie
    | Steak
```

**How do we create a record / function / something to represent the recipe above?**

I'm attempting to model something like this:

> What is the measure of the accompanying offerings? The accompanying
>   offering for a male or female sheep is an isaron12 of fine flour mixed
>   with a quarter of a hin13 of oil and a quarter of a hin of wine as a
>   wine libation. These are also [the accompanying offerings] for a goat
>   whether small14or large15 and whether male or female and for a ewe,
>   even if she is large. The accompanying offerings of a ram, however,
>   are two esronim mixed with a third of a hin of oil and a third of a
>   hin of wine as a libation. The accompanying offerings of a cow or a
>   calf, whether male or female, are three esronim mixed with a half of a
>   hin of oil and a half of a hin of wine as a libation.

Each accompanying offering is different depending on the animal being offered (sheep/goat/ram).

Comment: example would be `let LambReceipe = 3<Tablespoons>Oil + 16<ounces>Sugar + 3<Ounce>Butter` - this is just to illustrate what i'm looking for, very pseudo-code

Comment: You will probably need a normalized unit for amounts to use in the actual type, and then use conversion functions to create the instances, as explained in your previous question.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev fine, let's assume theres only 1 measure, how would we repesent a recipe with just 1 measure

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev attempting to model something like this https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-e_7W4zbx6Rc/XD6WyL2JtiI/AAAAAAAGvpU/-N_6w9Q_jechGEcb1Ss9zMILkGFq3eH_gCHMYCw/s0/chrome_2019-01-15_20-28-22.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your needs, I might *not* use F#'s units of measure system, and instead model your units as a discriminated union. The reason is because F#'s units of measure are treated as completely different types, so you can't write a list like `[ 3.0<Tablespoon>; 0.5<Cup> ]` as F# will throw a type error. But you *could* do something like the following:

```
type RecipeUnit =
    | Tablespoon
    | Cup
    | Ounce
    | Pound

type Ingredient =
    | Butter
    | OliveOil
    | Sugar
    | Salt

type RecipePart = { Amount: float
                    Unit: RecipeUnit
                    Item: Ingredient }

let pie = [
    { Amount = 10.0; Unit = Tablespoon; Item = OliveOil }
    { Amount = 1.0; Unit = Ounce; Item = Salt }
]
```

Or, to give an example with your actual data model:

```
type Unit =
    | Isaron
    | Hin

type Ingredient =
    | Flour
    | Oil
    | Wine

type OfferingPart = { Amount: float
                      Unit: Unit
                      Item: Ingredient }
type Offering = OfferingPart list

let sheepOffering = [
    { Amount = 1.0; Unit = Isaron; Item = Flour }
    { Amount = 1.0 / 4.0; Unit = Hin; Item = Oil }
    { Amount = 1.0 / 4.0; Unit = Hin; Item = Wine }
]

let goatOffering = sheepOffering

let ramOffering = [
    { Amount = 2.0; Unit = Isaron; Item = Flour }
    { Amount = 1.0 / 3.0; Unit = Hin; Item = Oil }
    { Amount = 1.0 / 3.0; Unit = Hin; Item = Wine }
]

// Etc.
```

Note that `1.0 / 3.0` is imprecise; if that's a problem, you'll want to model rational fractions (as either a tuple or a 2-item record; I'll assume you don't need help with this one).

P.S. I assume that "esronim" is the plural of "isaron", and that the two esronim mentioned in the ram's offering are of flour. If I got that wrong, adjust my example accordingly.